# Indexing files and full text search / query file contents in file with Elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have a bunch of PDF's that I want to have searchable. I was able to convert PDF's into text files for easier manipulation. I was able to index a test file with:

```
HOST = 'http://localhost:9200'
INDEX = 'test'
TYPE = 'attachment'
os.system('curl -X PUT "{}/{}/{}/_mapping" -d'.format(HOST,INDEX,TYPE) + ''' '{
                  "attachment" : {
                    "properties" : {
                      "file" : {
                        "type" : "attachment",
                        "fields" : {
                          "title" : { "store" : "yes" },
                          "file" : { "term_vector":"with_positions_offsets", "store":"yes" }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }' ''')
```

and then:

```
os.system('curl -X POST "{}/{}/{}" -d @'.format(HOST,INDEX,TYPE) + 'test.txt')
```

If I query like this:

```
os.system('curl "http://localhost:9200/test/_search" -d "{"query":{"match_all":{}}}"')
```

I get all results from test. The whole file is printed out in what I assume is some sort of encoding because I cannot read any of the printed contents.
Example:

```
{
  u'hits': {
    u'hits': [
      {
        u'_score': 1.0,
        u'_type': u'attachment', 
        u'_id': u'GWSlwJ63QvmsTcnksEDVAQ', 
        u'_source': {
          u'file': u'DE1pc3Npb24gU3RhdGVtZW50Ckl0IGlzIHRoZSBtaXNzaW9uIG9mIHRoZSBCdXJlYXUgb2YgTGFu\nZCBNYW5hZ2VtZW50IHRvIHN1c3RhaW4g........CBTb3V0aGVhc3Rlcm4gU3RhdGVzIFJN\nUAoKDA==\n', 
          u'title': u'test.txt'
        }, 
        u'_index': u'test'
        }
    ],
    u'total': 3, 
    u'max_score': 1.0
  }, 
  u'_shards': {
    u'successful': 5, 
    u'failed': 0, 
    u'total': 5
  }, 
  u'took': 43, 
  u'timed_out': False
}
```

**My questions are:**

1. Other than that `match_all:{}`, I can't query by a word contained in the file. How do I do a full text search on the contents of the file?
2. Is this the best approach at indexing files? I'll eventually have several thousands of them.
3. Is converting from PDF to TXT necessary in the first place?
4. With `"file": {"store":"yes"}` I assume that means the file is physically stored inside the ES cluster. If I change to "no", is the file still indexed and retrievable from a full-text search query?